# How to combine vertical menu with button icon and subcategories

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap for a project and I have a specific sidebar in mind. I'm trying to incorporate subcategories that use an accordion and a collapse menu for phones. The closest I've found is http://jsfiddle.net/JpJqD/2/, but it breaks when I try to envelope it with:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>

</div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the jquery for the button. All you need to do is set display:none on .panel in a media query, whichever width you prefer.

http://jsfiddle.net/JpJqD/116/

```
$(function(){

$('#sidebar > a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(!$(this).hasClass("active")){
            var lastActive = $(this).closest("#sidebar").children(".active");
            lastActive.removeClass("active");
            lastActive.next('div').collapse('hide');
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(this).next('div').collapse('show');

        }

    });

$('.open-link').click(function(){
    $('#sidebar').toggle();
});
});
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! I took the modifications just a bit further to avoid the need for the extra link and made the dropdown hidden on mobile... http://jsfiddle.net/khackett/JpJqD/117/